# MSAL Oauth EWS authentication - AcquireTokenForClient forces Visual Studio to skip to end

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oauth, exchangewebservices, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to set up app-only OAuth authentication for EWS to reach O365, following these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth#add-code-to-get-an-authentication-token

The project is going to be a Windows service (C# .NET 6 Console app), but right now I'm stepping through each line in Debug Mode (Visual Studio 2022), watching the Console.

```
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientID)
            .WithTenantId(tenantID)
            .Build();

var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };

var authResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync();
```

I ran it like this, and I got an error saying I needed to pass a credential, such as a cert or clientSecret. *The point I'm emphasizing is that it actually runs, seems to communicate with the server, and returns an error message.*

So I got a secret value from the Azure portal and ran it again like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("FIRST WRITELINE");
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientID)
            .WithClientSecret(mySecret)
            .WithTenantId(tenantID)
            .Build();

var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };

var authResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync();
Console.WriteLine("SECOND WRITELINE");
```

When I run the above code, even stepping line by line, as soon as it tries to process "AcquireTokenForClient().ExecuteAsync()" it immediately jumps out of this class and back to the method that called it. It gives absolutely no output, as if it crashed. It never reaches "SECOND WRITELINE", even if I have a breakpoint on it. It's inside of a try block, but it skips the catch and jumps OUT of this class altogether.

I've tried it with both Visual Studio 2019 and 2022, with the same results. Rebooted my machine, etc. I tried messing around with "WithDebugLoggingCallback()" in the chain, with no difference.

I don't know if it's a Visual Studio bug, or a problem with that method. Anyone seen something like this and resolved it?

Comment: did you find a solution to this? Hitting the same problem myself.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you need to call Result on the async task and remove the await. It should look like this:

```
var authResult = app.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync().Result;
```

Comment: I had the same issue and this resolved it. I'm not entirely sure it's the best solution, but it was a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your "Main" method signature and make sure that it is not:

```
async static void Main(string[] args)
```

Correct Main method should return Task:

```
async static Task Main(string[] args)
```